# UITableView Does not show data in ipad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have ipad app in which i am using tableView to show data but problem is that it does not show data in tableView here is code for setting cell value

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    if (tableView == tableCategory) {

        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;    

        ObjectData*theCellData = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text=theCellData.categoryTitle;

        return cell;
    }
    else if (tableView == tableSubCategory)
    {
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;    
        ObjectData*theCellData = [subCategoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *test = theCellData.subCategoryTitle;
        NSLog(@"Test Cell is %@",test);
        cell.textLabel.text = test;

        return cell;    
    }
    else if(tableView == tablePublish)
    {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;    

        GetPublishData *theCellData = [publishArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@ in:%@:%@",theCellData.UserName,theCellData.ContentTitle,theCellData.ContentType,theCellData.Catgeory,theCellData.SubCategory];
        NSLog(@"Test Cell is %@",test);
        cell.textLabel.text = test;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = theCellData.ContenAddedTime;

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;  

        GetPublishData *theCellData = [publishArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *test = theCellData.ContentDescription;
        cell.textLabel.text = test;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

I have tableView delegate and dataSource but still does not show anything while check count in array it shows items in it but does not show data in tableview
the data which i am showing for else table is not working

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your whole method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: @zbMax edited please check the code

Comment: Are the table view methods ever called?

Comment: did u wrote [yourTableview reloadData];

Comment: yes i wrote tableView reloadData

Comment: tableView methods are called are other table data is shown except else

Comment: if (tableView ==tableCategory ) ,if(tableView==tableSubCategory) ,  else if(tableView==tablePublish) are the above comparisions correct ? Did you try with "isEqualToString" ?

Comment: Do you have 3 distinct tableView in the same view controller?

Comment: @zbMax yes i have 4 different tableView in same view controll three showing values fourth one not showing

Comment: comparisions are true that is why those table show data

Comment: Which table doesn't show data?

Comment: the statement in else does not show data

Comment: Have you tried to add your `NSLog(@"Test Cell is %@",test);` is your else statement? Is it reached? What does it show?

Comment: @ZbMax it is not reaching there

Comment: So maybe @iSchmidt is on the right way. Check what is return by your numberOfRowsInSection method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What returns your method - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section? Can you show your code?

Also check that you set delegate and datasource for all of tables.

Excuse me for posting this like answer. I haven't reputation for posting in comments.

Comment: it is ok no proble i have set delegate and dataSource for all tables

Comment: And what about numberOfRowsInSection method? can you check it? How much of rows should be at this table?

Comment: they are also showing array count perfectly but it does not show in cell

Comment: One more thing: You can delete datasource and delegate from other tables and leave it just for problematic table, then you can debug method cellForRowAtIndexPath:. I think by this way you can find a problem.

Comment: Can you add a line NSLog(@"Test Cell is %@ for else case",test); to the else block? Did it shown in console?

also check method numberOfSectionsInTableView.

Answer (score 0):

check for the cell identifier.. have you given any custom cell identifier for the table cells? here you are mentioning it as

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```